# Seaborn PairGrid for time series data, with color code given by time

Tags: time-series, seaborn

In pandas, when you have time series data nicely put in a dataframe (meaning you have a datetime index and, say, two columns) you can plot the relation between the two columns on a scatter plot, and get the color code to represent the time:

```
df.plot.scatter('col1','col2',c=df.index)
```

How can you achieve this in a seaborn.PairGrid, with the off-diagonal elements given by regplot()?

I came up with this:

```
def make_regplot(*args,**kwargs):
    sns.regplot(*args,**kwargs,scatter=False)
    plt.scatter(*args,c=df.index)

g = sns.PairGrid(df)
g = g.map_diag(plt.hist)
g = g.map_offdiag(make_regplot)
```

I was wondering if there was a nicer solution, also in view of possible issues like this one https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1079.

Comment: This is the suggested solution from the issue you link to. So what other solution are you looking for?

Comment: Well, I'm wondering if it possible to do something like hue='something' directly in the pairgrid keyword arguments.

Comment: Yes, but `hue` must be a column of the dataframe, not the dataframe index. Also, it will then produce one regplot per hue, which may, or may not be desired.